# WPF - Scrolling Listbox in an Expander

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, expander

I have an `Expander` that I want to have a `ListBox` in.  When the I open the `Expander`, the `ListBox` just expands off the screen (rather than expanding to fill what is available and then scrolling).

Here is my XAML:

```
<DockPanel Margin="266.25,0,455,12" Name="dockPanel1">
    <StackPanel>
        <Expander Header="expander1" Name="expander1" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Grid>
                <Label>Testing</Label>
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <ListBox Name="lstBox"  FontSize="14" SelectionChanged="lstBox_SelectionChanged" />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
        </Expander>
        <Expander Header="expander2" Name="expander2" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Grid >

            </Grid>
        </Expander>
    </StackPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

When `Expander1` is opened then it just expands to the size of the `ListBox` (off the screen).  If I put a size on the grid (`Height="275"`), then it does not resize with the window.

I want it to stretch to the size of the window, but no more.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the Height property of ScrollViewer otherwise it will be the same size as it's child.  Here is some updated XAML:

```
<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel>
        <Expander Header="expander1" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <StackPanel>
                <Label>Testing</Label>
                <ScrollViewer Height="75">
                    <ListBox>

                    </ListBox>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </StackPanel>
        </Expander>
        <Expander Header="expander2">
        </Expander>
    </StackPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: But how can I set that to be the height of the window?  Can I do data binding to make that happen?

Comment: You could do a binding with syntax like this: {Binding ElementName=Window1, Path=Height} but that would lead to too large of a value.  I think instead you will need to a property to your window that is Height - SomeOffset.

Comment: Also, I imagine there is a better solution than what I just suggested.